# How to get a value from comment meta

Tags: comments, meta-value, comment-meta

I've add the field **country** in the comment form.
Working nice and I can see the value in the table commentmeta.

[image]

Now I try to display this value in my comment list.

In my **single.php** I call the list of comments:

```
<?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=format_comment'); ?>
```

In my **functions.php** I format the comment:

```
function format_comment() {  ?>
    <div class="comment">
        <p><?php comment_author(); ?></p>
        <p><?php get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'country', true ); ?></p>
        <p><?php comment_date('Y/m/d - g:i A'); ?></p>
        <p><?php comment_text(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

So... to get the value for the meta **country** I use

```
<?php get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'country', true ); ?>
```

Without success…

Comment: By "without success," I'm guessing that you mean that your call to `get_comment_meta()` appears to be returning nothing/`NULL`/an empty string?

Comment: Yes that it, sorry for the miss.

Comment: No worries - thanks for the exceptional formatting in your post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the Codex entry for `get_comment_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_meta), it appears that when the `$single` argument is set to `TRUE` (as you have done), the function returns a string. Try throwing an `echo()` into the works:

```
<?php echo get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'country', true ); ?>
```

Comment: helpfull, thank to show me the way.
Now it work with `<?php echo get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'country', true ); ?>`

Comment: Glad to hear it! Rock on, jeromeM ;)

Comment: what if you want to check if is exist first? i.e. not empty...?

Comment: @klewis it's normally not necessary - the `get_comment_meta()` call will return `false` or `null` in that case, and so the echo won't print out anything.

If you do want to check first though, I'd recommend just storing the output in a temporary variable. `$country = get_comment_meta( get_comment_ID(), 'country', true ); if( isset( $country ) ) echo $country;`